# Error message code blocks "no file or directory"

Tags: c, codeblocks

I've written and compiled files before but today I receive this error message

```
dawas-mbp:~ dawasherpa1$ /Users/dawasherpa1/Desktop/Programming 1/Strings/bin/Debug/Strings 
-bash: /Users/dawasherpa1/Desktop/Programming: No such file or directory
dawas-mbp:~ dawasherpa1$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **space** in the directory name "Programming 1", so that with

```
$ /Users/dawasherpa1/Desktop/Programming 1/Strings/bin/Debug/Strings
```

the shell tries to execute "/Users/dawasherpa1/Desktop/Programming" with the argument "1/Strings/bin/Debug/Strings". You have to enclose the entire path in quotation marks

```
$ "/Users/dawasherpa1/Desktop/Programming 1/Strings/bin/Debug/Strings"
```

or escape the space with a backslash

```
$ /Users/dawasherpa1/Desktop/Programming\ 1/Strings/bin/Debug/Strings
```

to execute your program.

Answer (score 0):

First, edit your answer and provide more informations with better language. Your question is hard to read. And what is your platform? Linux?

I see some answers:

- do you compiled program before clicked "run"?
- have you installed compiler and configured C::B to use it? Click `Options` and `Compiler`, check paths.
- maybe problem with output directory (`chmod 777`) ?

Comment: yes,the platform is linux. I am learning 'c',so far I was able to compile my files and practice but today when I compiled it,it showed the above message.